Error opening an HTTPS url with electron loadURL method
I have a simple app made with Electron that opens an HTTPS URL.
While loading, I get this error:
[21460:0611/195445.035:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

The page is opened without error, should I ignore it?
I'm using electron-forge 6.2.1, the app is very simple:
let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    webSecurity: true,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    show: false,
});
win.loadURL(url);


Even the app works without an issue , ignoring such error can lead to security issues.
The error suggest that  issue with parsing a certificate retrieved during URL load
you can use
ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true npm start
and for certification error log
ses.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
        console.error(`Certificate error: ${error} for ${url}`);
        callback(false); // Cancel the request
    });

you can use somthing like this
or you can use
 ses.on('select-client-certificate', (event, webContents, url, list, callback) => {
        console.log(`Client certificate requested: ${url}`);
        callback(); // Provide no client certificate
    });

If you like you can use both
If the URL load to fail I just put this if need to see  better log
win.webContents.on('did-fail-load', (event, errorCode, errorDescription, validatedURL) => {
        console.error(`Failed to load ${validatedURL}: ${errorDescription} (${errorCode})`);
    });

win.loadURL('https://example.com');

you can try different type of URL and test it ,
if the same error occur one option is you can try verifying certificate using something like OpenSSL

Thank you for the tip, however the did-fail-load event is not thrown. I can still see the log I posted before, but I dont see any error from your code.

Yes error won't go away just adding log of it to better understanding if fails , check and verify the certification

Sorry, I did not well explain. Your code doesn't log the error, it seems did-fail-load event is not thrown. I still see just the error I posted and not the log inside win.webContents.on('did-fail-load', method.

I have updated answer you can check it

const ses = session.fromPartition('persist:name'); add electron session in import.
